# Strange sampling results from statsmodels.api.GLM (Generalised linear model)

Tags: python, statsmodels

I encounter a problem in using python tool "statsmodels.api.GLM", which I cannot understand. I come here asking for helps.

I'm working on an example of (see the Section of) "Cubic and Natual Cubic Splines"
on this page https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/introduction-regression-splines-python-codes/  (data link is included in the page or [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QIHCTvHQIBpilzbNxGmbdEBEbmEkMd_K/view))

The problem is that.  After fitting the data, I try to predict values at given places of x (eg. the xp00 and xp01 in the following code). Then I find that, once the requested positions having different min and max (i.e., the xp01) from the training x-set (i.e., the xp), the result becomes something else, not at all my transitional expectation that, at the same position, the prediction should be exactly the same value, whatever how you made the request because the fit to the data is done and fixed.   I'm expecting the pred01 is overlapped with pred00, but just shorter a the left end.

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline

# read data_set
data = pd.read_csv("Wage.csv")

data.head()

data_x = data['age']
data_y = data['wage']

# Dividing data into train and validation datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = train_test_split(data_x, data_y, test_size=0.33, random_state = 1)



from patsy import dmatrix
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt


# Generating cubic spline with 3 knots at 25, 40 and 60
transformed_x = dmatrix("bs(train, knots=(25,40,60), degree=3, include_intercept=False)", {"train": train_x},return_type='dataframe')

# Fitting Generalised linear model on transformed dataset
fit1 = sm.GLM(train_y, transformed_x).fit()

# Prediction on splines
pred1 = fit1.predict(dmatrix("bs(valid, knots=(25,40,60), include_intercept=False)", {"valid": valid_x}, return_type='dataframe'))

# Calculating RMSE values
rms1 = sqrt(mean_squared_error(valid_y, pred1))
print(rms1)
#-> 39.4

# We will plot the graph for 70 observations only
xp = np.linspace(valid_x.min(),valid_x.max(),70)
xp00 = np.linspace(valid_x.min(),valid_x.max(),170)
xp01 = np.linspace(valid_x.min()+4,valid_x.max(),170)   # just shift the lower bound a bit




# Make some predictions
pred1 = fit1.predict(dmatrix("bs(xp, knots=(25,40,60), include_intercept=False)", {"xp": xp}, return_type='dataframe'))
pred00 = fit1.predict(dmatrix("bs(xp, knots=(25,40,60), include_intercept=False)", {"xp": xp00}, return_type='dataframe'))
pred01 = fit1.predict(dmatrix("bs(xp, knots=(25,40,60), include_intercept=False)", {"xp": xp01}, return_type='dataframe'))




SMALL_SIZE = 4
gamma=0.4
plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2),dpi=300)

# Plot the splines and error bands
plt.scatter(data.age, data.wage, facecolor='None', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.1)
#plt.plot(xp, pred1, label='Specifying degree =3 with 3 knots')
plt.plot(xp, pred1, color='r', label='Specifying degree =3 with 4 knots     xp')
plt.plot(xp00, pred00, color='g', label='Specifying degree =3 with 4 knots  xp00')
plt.plot(xp01, pred01, color='b', label='Specifying degree =3 with 4 knots  xp00')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(15,85)
plt.ylim(0,350)
plt.xlabel('age')
plt.ylabel('wage')
plt.show()
```

Well, I have no right to enclose the figure in the post! so please click the link below and check the strange results.  Perhaps not strange just myself don't know how to use it. I'm ready to see.

[the strange reuslts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFkGH.jpg) (URL :https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFkGH.jpg)

Thanks!!

Yanbin

Answer (score 0):

splines are a statefull transformation. That means that computing the splines needs parameters like knot location that are based on the data. This is similar to standardization that depends on mean and standard deviation of the sample.

Using formulas in statsmodels keeps track of those stateful transformation for transformations like splines that are provided by patsy. So, the original parameters for the statefull transformation are used when computing the transformed design matrix for new prediction points.

In the example code, the spline basis is computed separately for the training and test example. However, it specifies the interior knots to be the same in both cases.

My guess what happens in the example is that patsy adjusts the boundary knots to the transformation data. In that case, even if the interior knots are the same, the boundary knots differ.

As consequence, the B-spline basis will agree in the interior of the data space, but not for points close to the boundary.

A second source of differences is that removing the intercept from the spline basis can be a "global" transformation which will affect all spline basis columns and not just a single column. (I do not remember what patsy's default for removing the intercept is for the B-splines.)

Comment: Thanks! that clarifies what I've suspected.  Is there any option to avoid such standardization?  Or perhaps should recalculate the  corresponding knots when I changed the input range (even not sure what I'm speaking :D) ?

Comment: Recalculating knots doesn't help. All knots, interior and boundary/exterior knots need to be the same to have the same spline basis. AFAIR, patsy doesn't allow specifying boundary knots. The information to build a new design matrix with patsy is in the `design_info`. That is used internally in statsmodels to handle these transformations for predict.